# How does property decorator work internally using syntactic sugar(@) in python?

Tags: python, properties, decorator

I know that my question seems to be very similar to others. but it's not actually, I've searched a lot and couldn't find my answer.

As we know:

```
@mydecorator
def myfn():
    pass
```

is (exactly?) translated to :

```
def myfn():
    pass
myfn = mydecorator(myfn)
```

consider the following class:

```
class C:
def __init__(self, language):
    self._language = language

@property
def language(self):
    return self._language

@language.setter
def language(self, value):
    self._language = value
```

if we want to translate these to the function + assignment statement, for the getter there is no problem:

```
def language(self):
    return self._language
language = property(language)
```

but what about setter? :

```
def language(self, value):
    self._language = value
language = language.setter(language)
```

I did exactly what I had done before but that's not going to work.
after the previous stage(getter), label 'language' refered to the property object.
now it's reassigned to a function(function comes first)! so this language.setter isn't going to work it's not a property anymore.

I thought maybe there is an extra step when we use @ syntax. if it is, what is that? and can we say they are roughly similar to each other.

if it's not, for example when we use decorator with property objects they behave a bit more than just translation into function + assignment statement ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is exactly where you asked yourself if it was `(exactly?)` the same.

[PEP 318](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) mentions it rapidly:

> Current Syntax
>
> The current syntax for function decorators as
> implemented in Python 2.4a2 is:

```
@dec2
@dec1
def func(arg1, arg2, ...):
    pass
```

> This is equivalent to:

```
def func(arg1, arg2, ...):
    pass
func = dec2(dec1(func))
```

> **without the intermediate assignment to the variable func.** (emphasis mine)

So, that's why everything works fine when you use the `@decorator` syntax.

You could make it work by using a different name:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, language):
        self._language = language

    
    def language(self):
        return self._language
    language = property(language)
    
    
    def dummy_temporary_name(self, value):
        self._language = value
    language = language.setter(dummy_temporary_name)
    
    
c = C('fr')
print(c.language)
c.language = 'de'
print(c.language)

# fr
# de
```